# how to link plus or minus sign in c macro?

Tags: c, macros

my code is:

```
#define CHECK(x) if((x)==100)printf("%s = 100\n",#x);
#define C9(x) CHECK(x##9);CHECK(x##PLUS##9);CHECK(x##MINUS##9);
#define PLUS +
#define MINUS -

int main(){
 C9(123-45-67+8);
 return 0;
}
```

the macro expand to this(I add some \n to make code readable):

```
int main(){
 if((123-45-67+89)==100)printf("%s = 100\n","123-45-67+89");;
 if((123-45-67+8PLUS9)==100)printf("%s = 100\n","123-45-67+8PLUS9");;
 if((123-45-67+8MINUS9)==100)printf("%s = 100\n","123-45-67+8MINUS9");;;
 return 0;
}
```

And it is expected to expand to this :

```
int main(){
 if((123-45-67+89)==100)printf("%s = 100\n","123-45-67+89");;
 if((123-45-67+8+9)==100)printf("%s = 100\n","123-45-67+8+9");;
 if((123-45-67+8-9)==100)printf("%s = 100\n","123-45-67+8-9");;;
 return 0;
}
```

How to do it ?
Thanks

Comment: why does the 2nd if have two semicolons `;` and the 3rd one has three?

Comment: because I add semicolons `;` in each macro ..

Comment: Are you ever going to change `PLUS` to some other operator? (which is a very, very bad idea!) If not, why not use the symbols, but obfuscate the code?

Comment: I would use the comma instead the semicolon. so it is only one expression and you can use whitout brackets if it  follows an if or a loop.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you should define `PLUS` and `MINUS` prior to using. secondly I think you do not want to use `##` around `PLUS` and `MINUS` as so:

```
#define CHECK(x) if((x)==100)printf("%s = 100\n",#x);
#define PLUS +
#define MINUS -
#define C9(x) CHECK(x##9);CHECK(x PLUS 9);CHECK(x MINUS 9);

int main(){
 C9(123-45-67+8);
 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh,I am so fool

this code work

```
#define C9(x) CHECK(x##9);CHECK(x+9);CHECK(x-9);
```

it is easy =_=